# How to do a query to mysql database AFTER client`s request in nodejs/socket.io?

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

All examples i've seen were doing a query first and then send to client some info.

If I do a query FIRST and then use results in functions it works:

```
client.query(
  ('SELECT * FROM '+TABLES_USERS),
  function(err, results, fields) {
var Users = (results);
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.on('event1', function (data) {
          var requser = Users[data];
      socket.emit('event2', requser);
});
  });
    client.end();
  });
```

But now i need to do a query on client's request.
I tried something like this but query doesn't work:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.on('event1', function (data) {
        console.log('query required'); /*works*/
        client.query(
          ('SELECT * FROM '+TABLES_USERS+' WHERE id_user ='+data),
          function(err, results, fields) {
              if (err) {throw err; /*doesn't work*/
                console.log('error'); /*doesn't work*/ }
                console.log('query is done'); /*doesn't work too. so i think query just doesn't work cuz there are no error and no results*/
                socket.emit('event2', results);
                client.end();
                    });

 });
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? You need to provide more info about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using node-mysql-libmysqlclient instead of node-mysql. But if someone knows a way to do a query AFTER client's request in node-mysql, please tell me))

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you are not doing ok (in my opinion) in the example above:

1) You don't ask for login after the client is connected to Socket.IO, instead you check to see if his session contains data that can verify is he's connected.

You should read the article about [Express, Socket.IO and sessions.](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/), since it explains everything in detail (if you are using Express)

2) I think MongoDB, CouchDB and possibly other databases are better suited for realtime applications than MySQL.

Comment: This is not the whole code. It's part of it and i didn't wanna copy\paste all of it cuz it doesn't make any change on my question :)

Comment: Ok, but what I've written above still stands.

Comment: Thanx, it will be useful for me later anyway. I think i'm gonna use express but not now.